# setbackground of textview not working

Tags: java, android, calendar, textview

I am using ExtendedCalendarView to draw year and month days 
here is the link of ExtendedCalendarView [enter link description here](https://github.com/tyczj/ExtendedCalendarView)

Now I get Calendar programmatically and then selected day which I want, should change their background image 
Just like

```
ExtendedCalendarView extendedCalendarView = (ExtendedCalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendar);
GridView calendar = (GridView) extendedCalendarView.findViewById(999);
calendar.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int pos,long id) {
        TextView dayTV = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        dayTV.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }   
}
```

Now I face issue, the issue is to set background, when API level less than 17 its does not seems to work, the cell selected which I want to select but its background does not change.
Its working with XML
 `android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"`
  and there is no issue with that but I have constraints which prevent me that day could not selected, that's why I could not use XML.
Is there any way to change background when API less then 17

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// your code looks good if textview is inside GridView;
This code is for textview outside:

ExtendedCalendarView extendedCalendarView = (ExtendedCalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendar);
GridView calendar = (GridView) extendedCalendarView.findViewById(999);
TextView dayTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

calendar.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapter, View view, int pos,long id) {
dayTV.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
} 
}
```

Comment: How to access to get TextView directly 
TextView dayTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
I am using Adapter to draw days just like
public class CalendarAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
 @Override
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View v = convertView;
  LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   v = vi.inflate(R.layout.day_view, null);
   TextView dayTV = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   dayTV.setText(String.valueOf(day.getDay()));
   return v;
 }
}